# How to give variable to a KSH script with a CGI?

Tags: shell, ksh, cgi

index.sh is in the cgi-bin directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

echo 'Content-type: text/html

<html><body>
<form action=FOO.KSH method=POST>
<input type=submit value=fgrep style=width:42px>
<input type=text name=name type=text autofocus size=60>
</input></form>
<br>'
```

FOO.KSH

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

printf "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; 

echo $1
echo $QUERY_STRING
echo $(</dev/stdin)
```

**Q**: Why does the FOO.KSH gives an empty file if I send an "a" string in the index.sh's form?

Answer (score 0):

```
method=POST>
```

needed to be

```
method=GET>
```

Comment: Why? In FOO.KSH's last line `echo $(</dev/stdin)` is reading and displaying the POST data. And works for me.

Comment: It didn't worked for me :D GET or POST would be better?

Comment: As the “fgrep” button value indicates a search form, GET should be preferred. (Think about: if Google would use POST forms, how could I send you now to https://google.com/search?q=get+or+post+for+search+form ?)